# How do I get the Index of an UltraComboEditor ValueList Item?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, infragistics

I have an `UltraComboEditor` named ddltype

I set the values with an Enumeration:

```vb
ddlType.Items.Add(SalesPaymentType.CashPayment.Value, SalesPaymentType.CashPayment.DisplayName)
ddlType.Items.Add(SalesPaymentType.CheckPayment.Value, SalesPaymentType.CheckPayment.DisplayName)
ddlType.Items.Add(SalesPaymentType.CreditCardPayment.Value,  SalesPaymentType.CreditCardPayment.DisplayName)
```

When I try to set the SelectedIndex with

```vb
ddlType.SelectedIndex = ddlType.Items.ValueList.FindString(SalesPaymentType.CashPayment.DisplayName)
```

It returns 0 not found. It is not finding my entry.

Comment: How the `SalesPaymentType` is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any enumerated values can be added to the `UltraComboEditor` control as below:

```
ultraComboEditor1.Items.Add(new ValueListItem(value, value.ToString))
```

One of the `ValueListItem()` constructors gets `data value` and `display text`.

To find item by string:

```
ultraComboEditor1.SelectedIndex = ultraComboEditor1.FindString(SalesPaymentType.CashPayment.ToString)
```

But more reasonable to use the `FindByDataValue()`:

```
ultraComboEditor1.SelectedItem = ultraComboEditor1.ValueList.FindByDataValue(SalesPaymentType.CashPayment)
```

Pay attention, the `FindByDataValue()` requires a value, but not a text.